# Преобразование чисел из двоичной в десятичную систему счисления

Tags: алгоритм

Преобразуйте двоичное число (введено как последовательность символов) в десятичное и 16-ричное

Comment: Назначение: Преобразует двоичное число (введено как последовательность символов) в десятичное и 16-ричное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Алгоритм перевода в десятичную:
1010 = (1·2^3)+(0·2^2)+(1·2^1)+(0·2^0) = 10
Каждая цифра умножается на двойку в степени N, где N - длинна числа минус позиция цифры(начиная с 1), результаты складываются.

---

В шестнадцатеричную можно так:
1) Создается массив, в котором индекс - число в двоичной записи из четырех символов , а "наполнение" - в шестнадцатеричной.

> array[0011] = 3;
> array[1100] = С; 
> и т. д.

2) В начале добавляются нули так, чтобы количество цифр делилось на 4.
3) В цикле каждые четыре цифры меняются на элемент массива по такому индексу.

---

Делайте.